# Realtime plot from serial data arduino sensor running too slow

Tags: c#, arduino, invoke

i'm trying to make an EEG aplication, it recieves data from an arduino as a string, and updates a chart with it... the issue i'm having is that the program on the computer is too slow, and it falls behind the real time data on the arduino... the code i'm using for this is:

```
            SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
            String recvdata = sData.ReadLine();
            //LOG.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { LOG.AppendText("Received: " + recvdata); });

            double data;
            Double.TryParse(recvdata, out data);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { updatechart(new medicion("asd", tag, data)); });
            tag = null;
```

the program is slow most likely because the invoke, i can't update the chart with it because it throws an exception that the program is trying to access the chart from a different thread.

when i comment the update chart the program runs super fast...
on a different note, i'm loading tests from .txt files and that goes very fast because i don't have the invoke.

```
                       chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
                        //==recorded.Clear(); // borra lo que haya
                        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                        {
                            string reading = "";
                            while ((reading = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                string[] datos = reading.Split(',');
                                double data;
                                Double.TryParse(datos[0], out data);
                                updatechart(new medicion(datos[0], datos[1], data));
                            }
                        }
```

Does anyone have any idea of a different option i could use?

edit: Solved, as joel said, i grouped the reads on a list and after reading a few i updated the chart with all of them, making less invoke calls.

```
   List<medicion> mediciones = new List<medicion>();
        SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
        String recvdata;
        double data;

        while (sData.BytesToRead >= 5)  
        {
            recvdata = sData.ReadLine();
            if(Double.TryParse(recvdata, out data))
            {
                mediciones.Add(new medicion(recvdata, tag, data));
                tag = null;
            }

        }
            //LOG.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
              LOG.AppendText("Received: " + recvdata); });

     this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { updatechart(mediciones); });
        }
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Two questions. (1) What is this `updatechart` you're calling? (2) Can you set up your code so it reads ALL the available data, and only when there's no new data, calls Invoke on the updatechart?

Comment: thanks! that worked... the update is a process that takes the "medicion" (a class that contains a a double and 2 strins, one for the data (to save) one for a tag that goes with the data (usually null but some reads have tags)